# Sort letters in ascending order ('a-z') in Python after using value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I imported my data file and isolated the first letter of each word, and provided the count of the word. My next step is to sort the letters in ascending order 'a-z'. This is the code that I have right now:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(text.txt", names=['FirstNames'])
df 

df['FirstLetter'] = df['FirstNames'].str[:1]
df

df['FirstLetter'] = df['FirstLetter'].str.lower()
df

df['FirstLetter'].value_counts()
df

df2 = df['FirstLetter'].index.value_counts()
df2
```

Using .index.value_counts() wasn't working for me. It turned this output:

``````````
Out[72]: 
2047    1
4647    1
541     1
4639    1
2592    1
545     1
4643    1
2596    1
549     1
2600    1
2612    1
553     1
4651    1
2604    1
557     1
4655    1
2608    1
561     1
2588    1
4635    1
       ..
`````````
How can I fix this?
``````````

Comment: why are you trying to `index.values_counts()` - what is the goal you are trying to reach?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sort_index()` function. This should work `df['FirstLetter'].value_counts().sort_index()`

Comment: Using .sort_index() worked like a charm. Appreciate the help!